# Does the responsibilities of factory and mapper overlap?

Tags: design-patterns, mapping, automapper, factory

I am a bit confused as to what responsibilities should a mapper hold. Could you please provide me with more in-depth description of mutual  interdependence between object factory and object mapper. Should object mapper make use of object factory or should it create result objects on its own?

Answer (score 1):

The job of a factory (or an IoC/DI container) is to create new objects.

The job of the mapper is to create copies of existing objects.

That being said, the mapper does have to have an object to start with, and you've got 3 options there...

1. pass one into the mapping method (I would recommend doing this only when you have a specific reason to, otherwise use one of the other 2)
2. configure the mapper to use the factory or container, if applicable/registered/whatever
3. let the mapper create the objects on its own